# Issues with .htaccess file to make SEO Friendly URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm new to web development and i'm trying make SEO friendly URLs using .htaccess file at the root of my directory. I've modified my apache2.conf file so that it includes :

```
<Directory /home/sakyun/sites/> (Being my file directory that i changed)
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All (So that my .htaccess file is read)
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've enabdle rewrite mod with:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

I've restarted apache with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

My .htaccess is at the root of my directory and contains the following :

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on
# Rewrite for profile.php?Id=1&Name=Name
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ php/profile.php?Id=$1&Name=$2 [NC,L]
```

So to me it seems that everything is correct but when i load my page my url is still like this :

```
localhost/abc/php/profile.php?Id=1&Name=Name
```

Where i'm expecting something more like :

```
localhost/abc/profile/1/Name
```

Also i'm running UBUNTU 16.04 In a Virtual Machine not sure if that helps.
What am i doing wrong? 
Is apache even taking my .htaccess file into consideration?
If not what do i do to get this to work?

Comment: Rewrites doesn't _change_ the URL. What that rule does is simply taking a URL like `profile/1/name` and internally call the URL `php/profile,php?Id=1&Name=name`. If someone writes the target URL directly, that will still be what the client sees.

Comment: Well all i'm trying to do is make SEO friendly URLS instead of seeing the above type code, how do i go about with this? Any suggestions?

Comment: When you write the links, use the new format: `/abc/profile/1/name`. Since Apache will call the other (old) URL internally, it won't be revealed to the client. Another alternative (which I would prefer over adding a bunch of htaccess rules) is to use some router instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following `RewriteRule` only rewrite the URL internally.

```
RewriteRule ^/?abc/profile/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /abc/php/profile.php?Id=$1&Name=$2 [NC,L]
```

When users requested `localhost/abc/profile/1/Name`, the url browser shown is `localhost/abc/profile/1/Name` and they are actually viewing the page `localhost/abc/php/profile.php?Id=1&Name=Name`.

You have to add another `RewriteRule` to redirect user to SEO friendly URL.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/abc/php/profile.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Id=([^&]+)&Name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?abc/php/profile.php$ /abc/profile/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

It checks if users are requesting the URL `localhost/abc/php/profile.php`, and if containing query string `Id` and `Name`, redirect the users to SEO friendly URL. `%1` is backreference to first `([^&]+)` and `%2` is backreference to the second one `([^&]+)`, which matches all the characters except `&`.